# Python Lists - Highest & Lowest

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am creating a python program, to allow a user to input numbers and find the total, average, highest and lowest of the numbers inputted. my teacher has told me to improve the program by removing the first and last number(which i have now done ) inputted into the list and not to use the min and max functions.I am confused on how doing so.

```
totalList=[]
TotalNum = int(input("Please enter how many numbers are to be entered:"))
Change=TotalNum
Input=0
Total=0
while TotalNum>0:
    TotalNum = TotalNum - 1
    Input = int(input("Enter Number: "))
    totalList.append(Input)
    Total = Total +Input

while 1 == 1:
    totalList = totalList[1:-1]
    TotalList = totalList
    print("Total:" ,Total)
    print("Average:",Total/Change)
    print("Highest:",max(TotalList))
    print("Lowest:",min(TotalList))
```

Comment: he wants you to loop over the items in the list manually and locate the smallest and largest numbers in the list

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing the first and last numbers of the list, since lists are zero-indexed in python (meaning the first number is at index `0`), you'll want to change `totalList = totalList[1:-1]` to start from `0`, making it `totalList = totalList[0:-1]`.

However, we may want to use those `first` and `last` numbers when searching for the `maximum` and `minimum` numbers in the list. So, I think what your teacher may have meant was to use the first and last numbers as `min` and `max`, and update them as you search through the list.

I will show you finding the `minimum`, and then using the same idea you can find the maximum.

```
min_num = TotalList[0]
max_num = TotalList[-1]

for i in TotalList:
    if i < min_num:
        i = min_num

# print("Highest:",max_num)
print("Lowest:", min_num)
```

Note: You don't need the infinite `while 1 == 1:` loop, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_low(nums, index):
    lowest = None
    lowNum = float("inf")
    for num in nums:
        if num < lowNum:
            lowNum = num
            lowest = num
    highest = None
    highNum = -float("inf")
    for num in nums:
        if num > highNum:
            highNum = num
            highest = num
    Used = []
    newL = []
    for num in range(lowest, highest + 1):
        if num in nums and not num in Used:
            newL.append(num)
            Used.append(num)
    return newL[index - 1]
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5] 
print(find_low(numbers, 1))

#The second paramter, 1, finds the lowest number, not 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).